# Removing part of URL but don't redirect with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So the problem I'm looking at and haven't managed to solve!

For example the url is http://someurl.com/brands/brand
What I want to accomplish is that htaccess lets te request go to url: http://someurl.com/brands/brand but removes the "brands" part from the url.

Also if the url: http://someurl.com/brands is called the page "brands" needs to be displayed. So only when there is a brand after /brands/ it needs to do a URL rewrite to http://someurl.com/brand

I have tried this but this piece does a redirect to the new location witch doesn't exist.

```
RewriteRule ^onze-merken/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

So I need the above with out the redirect, it only needs to rewrite the URL.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

This is now my htaccess part where the rewriting is done!

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /onze-merken/(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# Only rewrite if the directory doesn't exist.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^((?!onze-merken/).+)$ /onze-merken/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(uploads/([a-z0-9_\-\.]+)/__images/custom/(.*)/)(.*)$ http://someurl.com/uploads/$2/__images/custom/$3/$4 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /brands/(\S+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!brands/).+)$ brands/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Check the complete htaccess file, I am still having issue's. it is the part where it says "onze-merken"

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error because it's still doing a redirect to the /brand page!

Comment: No this rule will not impact `http://domain.com/onze-merken` URL. You should clear your browser cache completely before testing this change.